# Angular 16 standalone app: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm creating a standalone app from scratch, I don't have an ngModule.

I'm creating a translation service, and a pipe to use it.

testing it on app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { I18nPipe } from './pipes/i18n.pipe';
import { I18nService } from './services/i18n.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ct-v4',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, I18nPipe],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'ct-v4';
    constructor(private i18nService: I18nService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.i18nService.initLanguage('en');
    }
}
```

My i18n service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class I18nService {
    private translations: { [key: string]: string } = {};

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    initLanguage(lang: string, isFallback = false): void {
        this.http.get(`/langs/${lang}.json`).subscribe({
            next: (data: any) => {
                this.translations = data;
            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.error(`Language file for ${lang} not found.`);
                if (!isFallback) {
                    console.info('Falling back to default language: en');
                    this.initLanguage('en', true);
                } else {
                    console.error('Even the default language "en" is missing. Stopping language initialization.');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    i18n(key: string): string {
        return this.translations[key] || key;
    }
}
```

The pipe itself is not complaining because it's also standalone,
I get this error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[AppComponent])[I18nService -> I18nService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

I'm not finding examples online on how to use services in standalone angular apps

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using `HttpClient` service but you don't provide the HTTP client. To fix it, go to your `app.config.ts` and add [`provideHttpClient()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/provideHttpClient) to the `providers`:

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
}
```

In case you don't have an `app.config.ts`, go to your `main.ts` and add the following where your app is bootstrapped:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
});
```

For more information, see the [standalone dependency injection guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#configuring-dependency-injection).

Comment: you're right! also, cool username!

Comment: What if I wanted to use `appConfig` simultaneously? If I use it, bootstrapApplication would have 3 parameters which is invalid.

Comment: @Afshar in this case you should add it to your `appConfig`. Will update my answer.