# Angular 17 Http client injection

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I am building a new app for testing with angular 17 trying to connect to a simple API rest. I am desperate to get this to work. I have asked chat GPT, reviewed stack's older posts and even download an old application, but with no success.

Here is my app config and the error:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ClienteService} from "./cliente.service";
import {ClienteComponent} from "./cliente/cliente.component";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClienteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule

  ],
  providers: [ClienteService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {ClienteComponent} from "./cliente/cliente.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/clientes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'clientes', component: ClienteComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

**cliente.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClienteService {

  private clienteUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.clienteUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/clientes';
  }
  getClientes(nombre?: string, telefono?: string, direccion?: string) {
    const params: any = { nombre, telefono, direccion };
    return this.http.get(this.clienteUrl, { params });
  }
```

**cliente.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ClienteService} from "../cliente.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
  styleUrl: './cliente.component.css'
})
export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit{

  clientes: any[] = [];

  constructor(private clienteService: ClienteService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clienteService.getClientes().subscribe((clientesResponse:any) => {
      console.log('Respuesta del servicio getAllClientes',clientesResponse);
      this.clientes=clientesResponse._embedded.clientes;


    });
  }

}
```

The problem is this:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_ClienteService -> _ClienteService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:5601:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6044:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6044:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:911:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:917:42)
    at Object.ClienteService_Factory [as factory] (cliente.service.ts:7:28)
    at core.mjs:6164:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:867:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:6163:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6033:33)
handleError @ core.mjs:11747
```

Comment: don't think you want this in app.module: providers: [ClienteService]

Comment: @Rachel, if you use "standalone" component -your ClientComponent is- you inject the Http in providers like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163778/angular-16-standalone-app-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-httpclient). Futhermore, you need add as provider also the service. As you're using Modules, I suggest avoid standalone component. NOTE: Really the "search lab" it's very poor

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are mixing Modules and Standalone Components. As of Angular 17 everything is standalone by default, unless you specify otherwise.

You have 2 options.

1. Don't use stand alone components, make your components part of modules, then the import arrays in the modules should work.
2. Work without modules and make the app completely standalone. As intended from Angular 17

If you started a project in angular 17, I suggest against option number one.

For start, go to `main.js` and add `provideHttpClient(withFetch())` to the providers array. Insted of importing HttpClientModule in your AppModule.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Thank you. was struggling a lot with this and this answer resolved my issue.

Answer (score 20):

Anyhow, adding `provideHttpClient()` to the default appConfig providers list solves the same problem for me.

So the default src/app/app.config.ts looks like this.

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};
```

Even though I don't have an answer to how that works underneath, @vbartalis' reply makes sense as it seems to me.

Comment: Standalone components are documented here, including sample for `bootstrapApplication`: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Angular 17.2.3 and encountered this error as well. `provideHttpClient(withFetch())` as mentioned in the above comments didn't work for me and this is how I solved the issue:

modify the `app.config.ts` file to the following:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), provideHttpClient()]
};
```

Comment: This helped me, when moved my app from module based - in to stand alone mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using standalone components allows you to use the component like a module, so put your service inside the " @component{ " inside of "providers: [service]". Exactly the same way as you would in a module

example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente',
  standalone: true,
->imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
->providers: [ClienteService],
  templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
  styleUrl: './cliente.component.css'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your appcomponent.ts add HttpClientModule to the imports array after the styleUrls array. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by replacing the default "appConfig" part in the main.ts file with: {providers:[provideHttpClient(withFetch())]}. The code looked like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers:[provideHttpClient(withFetch())]})
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [ClienteService],  // <-- Add this line
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
  styleUrl: './cliente.component.css'
})
```

this should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This works on my **Angular 17** new app :

src\main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

src\app\app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations(), provideHttpClient(withFetch())]
};
```

you can use also :

```
provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
```

etc.

see official doc for Angular >= 17 : https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup

Answer (score -1):

If your're using Angular 17 you'll probably have app.config.ts file.
Move on it.
Into they provide array add provideHttpClient() import